# How to perform standardization and normalization on features from different feature engineering process?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm working with a dataset where each sample contains both numeric and text data. Therefore multiple methods are employed to build the training feature matrix from the dataset. For each sample in the dataset, I construct a vector representation from 3 parts.

1. Doc2Vec vector representation for paragraph text: I use the [`gensim` implemetation of paragraph vector](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-doc2vec-lee-py) to encode the text into a 100-D vetors of floats between `[-5, 5]`
2. One-hot encoded vector for text label: Each sample in the dataset has zero or more text label, I aggregate out all of the unique labels used in the dataset and encode it into a binary array containing only 0 and 1. For example, if the complete set of labels is `[Python, Java, JavaScript, C++]` and a sample contains labels `Python` and `Java`, the resulted vector will be `[1, 1, 0, 0]`.
3. Numeric data & categorical data:

   - Numeric data fields are built into the feature vector as is
   - Categorical data are mapped to integers and built into the feature vector

The resulted feature matrix looks something like below

```
[
  [-1.02, 1.33, 2.35, -0.48, ... -4.11, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 235, 11.5, 333],
  [-0.22, 3.03, 1.95, -0.48, ... -4.11, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 233, 22, 333],
  [-2.07, -1.33, -2.35, -0.48, ... -4.11, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 102, 13, 333],
  [-4.32, 4.33, 1.75, -0.48, ... -4.11, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 98, 8, 333],
]
```

My question is, should I apply any standardization or normalization on the dataset? If so, should I do it before or after concatenating different parts of feature?

I'm using scikit-learn and the major algorithm I using will be Gradient Boosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to process features separately: you should apply standardization or normalization only on the original numerical features, you shouldn't do it for doc2vec, OHE or encoded categorical features.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Could you please refer to the article stating this principle of "only standardize numerical features"? Much appreciated

Comment: Also, for standardization, is there a strict rule of standardization only **after** train-test split/CV split?

Comment: 1. For example this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399430/does-categorical-variable-need-normalization-standardization Basically OHE values are 0 or 1, so normalizing the won't change much. But the more important thing that for gradient boosting monotonic transformations don't change much because the order of values is important
2. Yes. It is a strict rule. You use validation data to see model performance on the unseen data, so all transformations should be fitted on train data and then applied to valid/test data